# Wrap higher order function into progress bar

Tags: scala, generics, iteration, progress-bar, higher-order-functions

I have an iteration module which can apply an arbitrary function ([Build generic reusable iteration module from higher order function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59100295/build-generic-reusable-iteration-module-from-higher-order-function)) and would love to wrap it into a progressbar.

```
val things = Range(1,10)
def iterationModule[A](
                        iterationItems: Seq[A],
                        functionToApply: A => Any
                      ): Unit = {
    iterationItems.foreach(functionToApply)
}

def foo(s:Int) = println(s)

iterationModule[Int](things, foo)
```

A basic `progressbar` could look like:

```
import me.tongfei.progressbar.ProgressBar
val pb = new ProgressBar("Test", things.size)
things.foreach(t=> {
  println(t)
  pb.step
})
```

But how can the function which is passed to the iterator module be intercepted and surrounded with a `progressbar`, i.e. call the `pb.step`?

An annoying possibility would be to pass the mutable `pb` object into each function (have it implement an interface).
But is it also possible to intercept and surround the function being passed by this stepping logic?
However, when looping with `Seq().par.foreach`, this might be problematic.

I need the code to work in Scala 2.11.

### edit

A more complex example:

```
val things = Range(1,100).map(_.toString)

def iterationModule[A](
                        iterationItems: Seq[A],
                        functionToApply: A => Any,
                        parallel: Boolean = false
                      ): Unit = {
  val pb = new ProgressBar(functionToApply.toString(), iterationItems.size)
  if (parallel) {
    iterationItems.par.foreach(functionToApply)
  } else {
    iterationItems.foreach(functionToApply)
  }
}

def doStuff(inputDay: String, inputConfigSomething: String): Unit = println(inputDay + "__"+ inputConfigSomething)

iterationModule[String](things, doStuff(_, "foo"))
```

The function should be able to take the iteration item and additional parameters.

### edit 2

```
import me.tongfei.progressbar.ProgressBar

val things = Range(1,100).map(_.toString)

def doStuff(inputDay: String, inputConfigSomething: String): Unit = println(inputDay + "__"+ inputConfigSomething)

def iterationModulePb[A](items: Seq[A], f: A => Any, parallel: Boolean = false): Unit = {
  val pb = new ProgressBar(f.toString, items.size)
  val it = if (parallel) {
    items.par.iterator
  } else {
    items.iterator
  }
  it.foreach { x =>
    f(x)
    pb.step()
  }
}
iterationModulePb[String](things, doStuff(_, "foo"))
```

After a little discussion I figured out how to use a Seq with standard iterators.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For **Scala** `2.13` this would be the most general form.

```
import me.tongfei.progressbar.ProgressBar

def iterationModule[A](items: IterableOnce[A], f: A => Any): Unit = {
  val (it, pb) =
    if (items.knowSize != -1)
      items.iterator -> new ProgressBar("Test", items.knowSize)
    else {
      val (iter1, iter2) = items.iterator.split
      iter1 -> new ProgressBar("Test", iter2.size)
    }

  it.foreach { x =>
    f(x)
    pb.step()
  }
}
```

*Note: most of the changes are just to make the code more generic, but the general idea is just to create a function that wraps both the original function and the call to the **ProgressBar***.

---

### Edit

A simplified solution for `2.11`

```
def iterationModule[A](items: Seq[A], parallel: Boolean = false)
                      (f: A => Any): Unit = {
  val pb = new ProgressBar("test", items.size)

  val it = if (parallel) {
    items.iterator.par
  } else {
    items.iterator
  }

  it.foreach { a =>
    f(a)
    pb.step()
  }
}
```

Comment: Awesome. Unfortunately, I need to code for 2.11. Could you help me translate it?

Comment: Also, your function is only taking a single argument - this might be problematic. How could this be extended to support multiple arguments?

Comment: I added a more complete example. Is it clearer why I want to be able to pass additional parameters?

Comment: Great. But `IterableOnce` seems to be a 2.13 thing only? And the `knownSize` is not available for a regular `Iterable`. So how could this be applied to 2.11? Why do you assume iterableOnce? For me a Seq would be enough (i.e. iteration does not destroy/ consume the elements).

Comment: We just did concurrent edits ;) Why did you remove the iterator in the 2.11 solution? I.e. why not use it with `val it = if (parallel) {
    items.iterator
  } else {
    items.par.iterator
  }`

Comment: @GeorgHeiler Just added them.